# how to make an image spin continuously without changing its position in processing?

Tags: processing, image-rotation

I'm making a virtual deejay with processing. it works with blob detection which trains the camera to read color from and interact with it. So I'm having a record image as png on the interface so I want it to spin the image as a real DJ. However, when I use rotate, it changes the position of the image and it is not spinning, so how can I solve this problem? 
The code that I provided is only the part that has the Image, it is not the whole code of the application.

```java
void setup() {

    size(1280, 720);

    String[] cameras = Capture.list();
    printArray(cameras);
    video = new Capture(this, 1280, 720);
    video.start();
    prev = createImage(video.width, video.height, RGB);
    trackColor = color(255, 0, 0);

    rec = loadImage("rec.png");  
    slide = loadImage("slide.png");  
    slider = loadImage("slider.png");
    frameRate(150);

}

void draw() {

    video.loadPixels();
    image(video, 0, 0);
    //this makes the camera flips
    image(video,0, 0, width, height); 
    translate(width, 0);
    scale(-1.0, 1.0);
    image(video,0, 0, width, height); 

    //the image That need to be spinning
    rotate(millis() * 0.0005);
    tint(255, 180);
    image(rec,100,200,465,465);
    noTint();

}
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem with a basic rectangle instead of images and camera feeds?

Answer (score 0):

You need to isolate the image spinning into a separate coordinate system using [pushMatrix()](https://processing.org/reference/pushMatrix_.html)/[popMatrix()](https://processing.org/reference/popMatrix_.html):

```
//isolate coordinate
pushMatrix();
//the image That need to be spinning
    rotate(millis() * 0.0005);
    tint(255, 180);
    image(rec,100,200,465,465);
    noTint();
//exit local coordinate system, return to Processing's global coordinates    
popMatrix();
```

Check out the [2D Transformations Processing tutorial](https://processing.org/tutorials/transform2d/) for more details.

Additionally you might want to rotate the image from the centre, in which case you can:

1. move to the centre of the image
2. rotate
3. move back to the top left corner and render the image

Example code:

```
//isolate local coordinate system
pushMatrix();
    //move local coordinate system to the centre of the image
    translate(rec.width * 0.5,rec.width * 0.5);
    //rotate
    rotate(millis() * 0.0005);
    //move local coordinate system back to the top left corner of the image
    translate(-rec.width * 0.5,-rec.width * 0.5);
    //render image
    tint(255, 180);
    image(rec,100,200,465,465);
    noTint();
//exit local coordinate system, return to Processing's global coordinates    
popMatrix();
```